# Numeric keys are pressed in chrome but not in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome, firefox

I have an input field in which i am taking phone number as input. I am applying some masking for phone formatting. Issue is its working perfectly fine in Chrome but in Firefox it did't allow us to enter any key. Seems like the field is disabled.

```
$("[id$=txtPhone]").keydown(function (event) {
            debugger
                if (event.keyCode == 8) {
                    return true;
                }
                if ($("#txtPhone").val().length <= 20) {
                    if ($("#txtPhone").val()) {
                        if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57)) { }
                        else return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || (event.keyCode == 43)) { }
                        else return false
                    }
                }
                else return false;
            });
```

Your help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you.

Comment: Try `if (event.which == 8) {`.. Replace all `event.keyCode` with `event.keyCode || event.which` and try...

Comment: Its not working :(

Comment: @Rayon its still not working. i tried.

Comment: Do share a fiddle so that one can work on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works both in Chrome and Firefox

```
function isNumber(evt) {
            evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```